# The image is cropped when the window is resized

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I decided to migrate my application from WindForms to WPF and faced the following problem: My image is cropped inexplicably. 
Can you help me? What am I doing wrong?

***Before resizing***

https://ibb.co/z4yYdJn

***After resizing***

https://ibb.co/6J60Sfc

```
<Window x:Class="ClientWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClientWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Test WPF" Height="535" Width="567" Background="#FF1D1E20">

    <Grid>

        <Image x:Name="back_1" Source="/Resources/background_1.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="None"/>
        <Image x:Name="back_2" Source="/Resources/background_2.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Stretch="None"/>
        <Image Margin="192,75,188,236" Width="160" Height="160" Source="/Resources/logo.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. Image cropped due to property: Margin="192,75,188,236"